# How do you add xml document info with scala.xml?

Tags: xml, scala, document, creation

First of all:

- I am aware of anti-xml, and scales, but I would like to use standard scala.xml
- I prefer to build xml document using explicit methods, not with implicit xml syntax built into Scala

Ok, so I have such piece of code:

```
val text = new scala.xml.Text("just a text")
val root = new scala.xml.Elem(null,"element",null,scala.xml.TopScope,text)
val doc = new scala.xml.Document()
doc.docElem = root
println(doc.toString())
```

Almost good but as result I get:

```
<element>just a text</element>
```

and I would like to get XML header too, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element>just a text</element>
```

**Question:** How to add it?

*Of course in common-sense way, not some hacking with extra verbatim `println` with header ;-).*

Comment: You are using an awesome language like Scala where you could say `val xml = <node> input </node>` and you dont prefer that? ;) Its okey, because its your choice, but could you tell me please why is it better to use the "other way"?

Comment: @OverStack, Because this feature is a flaw actually. Word from me, it is very fragile to any typos, so you don't see your error until it bites you. Second thing -- the fact the featue exists, it does not mean you should use it. Word from others: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/working-with-scalas-xml-support and there was a piece about HTML in VB, but I cannot find it right now.

Comment: @greenoldman Is it just me or your code gives a Null Pointer Exception?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only solution I've found is to add the following code

```
val writer : PrintWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out)
XML.write(writer,root,"utf-8",true,null)
writer.flush()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's odd that scala.xml does not have something more direct.

Comment: One more thing -- it is more useful (in general) to use `StringWriter` than `PrinterWriter` (because then it is very easy to get output xml as string).